# Wordpress CSS Center Table

Tags: css, wordpress, center

I'm trying to center the login table for my website on desktop. On mobile, it's centered, for some reason on desktop it's not. I tried width and margin auto in the custom CSS but that didn't work. Any input is appreciated.

https://grahmlux.com/my-account

Comment: Please read [ask]. We need a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly figured out the fix yet, but it's not a matter of mobile vs. desktop - the code in that section is the same for both. In fact, if you narrow the width of a desktop window to just under 980px, the login fields will be centered. There's something that happens just as it goes to 980px+ that then flops the login fields over to the left. Maybe there's a max-width on the fields or their container?

The solution may be to dig into the woocommerce css files. As a kludge, you could create a wrapper around the login area with margin: 0 auto to keep it centered and specify a maximum width so it doesn't go over 980px.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
.woocommerce .col2-set,
 .woocommerce-page .col2-set {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
}
```

on desktop this is kicking into play. and thus your login is floated left.  take the float off and margin: auto;

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
.woocommerce .col2-set,
 .woocommerce-page .col2-set {
  width: 45%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

You'll need to be careful that style isn't too universal. As such - you might be better targetting the login itself.

```
#customer_login{
  margin:auto;
  width: 45%;
  margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of those pieces of code, and strangely, it didn't work. I actually tried the same thing a few days ago. No result so far...